# What is schemaVersion for azure SDK toolchain 2.9

Tags: azure, sdk

I am getting the below error with msbuild. I have microsoft azure tools version 2.9 , upgraded.

```
c:\...\ServiceDefinition.csdef(2,123): error CloudServices051: The XML specification is not valid: The 'schemaVersion' attribute is invalid - The value '2014-06.2.4' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition:SchemaVersion' - The Enumeration constraint failed.
```

So what is schemaVersion for 2.9 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schemaVersion for the Azure SDK 2.9 is:

```
schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6"
```

You can verify this by creating a new Azure Cloud project targeting Azure SDK 2.9 and looking at the `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg` file.